# Help in regular expression and store results

Tags: regex, perl

HI all, 
I have a text file include this:

```
set_global_assignment -name FA "titan VII"
set_global_assignment -name DE ASDF3HF
```

I want to use perl to find out and extract the result of FA (result: titan VII) and DE (the result is: ASDF3HF). I only know basic on regular expression, i am not used to do expression and store this output. please help
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($fa,$de);

open DATA,'<', $file or die

while(<DATA>) {
        if(/set_global_assignment -name FA\s(.*)/) {
                $fa = $1;
        }elsif(/set_global_assignment -name DE\s(.*)/) {
                $de = $1;
        }
}
print "FA = $fa\nDE = $de\n";
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/FHC1j)

Comment: thanks alot, can we delete the " .. ", just get FA only, so that later no need to process again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %result;
while(<DATA>){
    $result{$1} = $2  if /^set_global_assignment -name (.+?)\s+(.+)$/;
}
print Dumper \%result;


__DATA__
set_global_assignment -name FA "titan VII"
set_global_assignment -name DE ASDF3HF
```

**output:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'DE' => 'ASDF3HF',
          'FA' => '"titan VII"'
        };
```